# Stack Overflow on social networks (LinkedIn, Facebook, hi5, Orkut)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, social-networking

We now have groups for promoting Stack Overflow on some social networking sites. They are [quasi-official](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6885/stackoverflows-presence-on-facebook-could-be-a-bit-better/18644#18644).

Everyone's welcome to join any of them.

- [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=753957) --- promote your Stack Overflow profile on your online CV (looking for administrators).
- [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow), [Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=28714318518) --- find fellow Stack Overflow users.
- [hi5 Group](http://hi5.com/friend/group/3764799--StackOverflow--front-html)
- [Orkut Community](http://www.orkut.com/Main#Community.aspx?cmm=50870412)
- [Google+](https://plus.google.com/+StackExchange/posts)

Currently I'm the sole administrator for the LinkedIn group. I don't want to be; LinkedIn requires an administrator to approve all new members.

What does everyone reckon is best practice for these sort of groups? I was thinking that we could use similar rules to Stack Overflow — if you have over 4000 reputation points you're welcome as an administrator, that sort of thing.

If you are a member of a networking site not already listed, please add it here.

Comment: What abount Google+???

Comment: @Juan Sebastian Totero - Google+ doesn't really have groups or fan pages yet. They have their own thing called Sparks, but that's more of a search filter.  I'm sure there will be an equivalent once it gets up to speed.

Comment: That Orkut link seems broken...

Comment: Looks like there is one now: https://plus.google.com/+StackExchange/posts - I assume it's (quasi-)official?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I originally posted this before either meta or stackexchange existed, just after the original SO beta. To be honest I'm not sure of the value of a stackexchange community as opposed to ones for each site - I might want to hear about programming questions on my Facebook, but that doesn't mean I also want to see posts about the huge range of alternate topics.

Comment: @Keith oh, thanks -- community wiki obscures the original posting date and I didn't look at the history, so I totally missed that.  (If I recall correctly, this question was nominated for closure as "off-topic - belongs on a per-site meta" or similar, and I saw it in a review queue.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio yeah, I wrote it on Stackoverflow, it got migrated to meta.Stackoverflow shortly after that was created, then it got migrated here. I'm not sure why, this question and the discussion has always been specific to SO.

Comment: @Keith until a few months ago meta.SO was *also* the meta site for the whole network.  In April they were split apart -- SO got its own meta, the old meta.SO got renamed meta.SE (since most questions *weren't* about SO), and some questions that really were SO-specific got migrated to the new meta.SO.  Old SO-only questions mostly didn't, so people are finding them now and saying "doesn't belong on meta.SE".  No worries, but that's what happened and why this question is getting a little attention now.

Answer (score 6):

LinkedIn has [an API](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/linkedin) in development (it's in private beta at the moment).  It may be possible to automate the group management when this is availble.  Perhaps there could even be a field in the Stackoverflow profile where you can enter your LinkedIn username and it would automatically sign you up for the group?

But say I join the LinkedIn group, what then?  Other than being able to identify fellow Stackoverflow users by the badge on their LinkedIn profile, what are the reasons to join?

It would perhaps be more useful to link to LinkedIn from my Stackoverflow profile page.  And also to link to my [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net) profile.  You can add text links on your Stackoverflow page at present, but it might be nice to be able to have an Ohloh/LinkedIn badge on there.

Answer (score 5):

There's also a [Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=28714318518) which may interest those who prefer groups instead of pages. :-)

Comment: Updated post and cross-pollinated. Want to trade admin rights?

Comment: Right, I've just joined the page now too. :-)

Comment: I've send a friend request - the add Admin menu only seems to let me pick friends.

Comment: Hahaha, I guess it's part of their anti-spam measure or something (on a similar note, I can only invite friends to join my group). I've added you now.

Comment: Admin send and pending.

Comment: Yay! Now we can go forth and conquer! :-)

Comment: ... and which is now "scheduled to be archived"...

Comment: @fretje: :-( That makes me sad, but I can't say I didn't expect it. But, never fear! Google+ will take over the world anyway. :-P

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook group is open - anyone can join.

The LinkedIn group I have to manually approve everyone. If you've just asked to join (and quite few just have) please be patient.

How should we decide on administrators?

Comment: For my Facebook group I just admin anybody who has high karma, and whom I have at least dealt with some of the time. :-) (The latter is optional; the spirit of SO is that "experienced" users should be granted some responsibilities.)

Answer (score 2):

I created a reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow

It's probably a duplicate of the programming reddit though.  I'm not sure what would be on the stackoverflow reddit that wouldn't be on the programming reddit.

Anyway, if you think of a link that should go there, then feel free to post it.

Comment: What's supposed to happen there? Post stories about SO and meme it out the wazoo?