# What about job postings under the stackoverflow LinkedIn group?

Tags: discussion, community, jobs, linkedin

I know that each of the Trilogy sites links into jobs.joelonsoftware.com, sorted by the appropriateness of the categories to the site in question.

Has there been any consideration of posting those to the LinkedIn group? Perhaps via an official channel?

I've asked this question on the stackoverflow group on LinkedIn, too :)

Comment: Subjective and Best Practices was not required for this post.

Comment: Given the recent annoucement: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/introducing-stack-overflow-careers/ ... probably not :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been the sole admin of the LinkedIn group (me on [SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/905) and [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/in/keithhenry)) since I proposed it in [Stack Overflow on social networks (LinkedIn, Facebook, hi5, Orkut)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15815).

I'd welcome Jeff and co to the group - anyone who's a moderator on here would be welcome as an admin on the LinkedIn group. I'd welcome anyone with a decent rep from any of the SO sites as an admin - currently I have to manually accept all members, so sorry for any delays.

Better links is a good idea - lots of recruiters use LinkedIn, but they don't really know SO.

I think we would benefit from adding a LinkedIn ['application'](http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=application_directory) (basically a profile plug-in) to display [SO flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair), but I haven't got round to looking at that in detail yet (I probably will next time I'm job hunting).

It should be possible using the LinkedIn API to post and update jobs from http://jobs.joelonsoftware.com to the group discussion board, but I'm not sure of the value - I spend more time here than on LinkedIn, so I'm more likely to see a relevant job advert on here than on there. I'd happily support someone else doing it if they felt that it would really help though.

Comment: Sorry - I deleted my Linked-In account some time ago. It was adding absolutely no value to my life. Nor does Facebook, althought I am contemplating going back onto twitter.

Comment: I find LinkedIn useful when job-hunting, the rest of the time it's a work-safe alternative to Facebook. It might be a location thing - LI is used by lots of UK recruiters when they're searching for CVs, it would be a lot less useful if they weren't.

Comment: I wouldn't personally delete a LinkedIn profile - thoguh certainly mine goes through fits and starts of activity. Keeping in contact with former co-workers is helpful, especially if you may be job hunting.

Comment: I mostly agree with Keith and warren on general usefulness of LinkedIn: it makes it easy to keep your (brief) CV always up-to-date; it's good for seeing what old colleagues are up to; and it definitely seems to be popular as a reqruiting channel, also here in the Nordics. (I've got several job offers through my network — all of which would have been somewhat relevant and interesting, had I not already been employed at an even more interesting place.)

Comment: There's a linkedin group?!? Arg - maintain anonymity vs acquire real world connections. Dilemma.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if they would. As far as I am aware the Linked In group is not controlled by Jeff and co, but started by the community.

It could potentially be another revenue stream, although as far as I am aware Linked-In already caters for this.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't - I'd welcome them as admins if they asked.