# Is there a LinkedIn application for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, reputation, linkedin

I think integrating Stack Overflow with [LinkedIn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn) by showing Stack Overflow application in the LinkedIn profile will help increase the attractiveness of a profile.

By just showing Stack Overflow reputation points in the LinkedIn profile it would add value to the profile/resume. For a recruiter this number will mean one more parameter to shortlist, as Stack Overflow reputation point tells about how much a person's solutions, answers and thinking is appreciated by others, his/her technical knowledge and his/her ability to explain, communicate, and convince.

Is there an application already or in development? I did look around a little bit and didn't see any open SDK to develop such application on my own, though I see LinkedIn provide some APIs. Is there something in the pipeline?

Comment: SO provides APIs too - http://stackapps.com/

Comment: You can write your own app and gain extra kudos on your linkedIn by saying hey, look, here is a linkedin app that I wrote that pulls the reputation from StackOverflow and here is my rep of 1. For more info go to http://stackapps.com

Comment: This is a http://meta.stackoverflow.com question

Comment: Haha @Igor, was that a little backhanded?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/what-about-job-postings-under-the-stackoverflow-linkedin-group

Comment: possible duplicate of [IS it possible to show SO flair on Linkedin](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22716/is-it-possible-to-show-so-flair-on-linkedin)

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.
See
[Is there any value in creating an app that will link SO and SF rep with LinkedIn profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3635/is-there-any-value-in-creating-an-app-that-will-link-so-and-sf-rep-scores-with-li)
[Is it possible to show the Stack Exchange flair on LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22716/is-it-possible-to-show-so-flair-on-linkedin)