# Is this a fake Stack Overflow Facebook page? If not, what is it?

Tags: discussion, facebook

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15815/stackoverflow-on-social-networks-linkedin-facebook-hi5-orkut), the official Facebook page for Stack Overflow is [this one](http://www.facebook.com/pages/stackoverflow/11239244970), with 2,400+ fans.

So what's [this Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Stack-Overflow/105665906133609)?

I do find the "Related Global Posts" on the imposter page absolutely hysterical though...

[image: Facebook FAIL]
<sub>(source: [gitlin.name](http://josh.gitlin.name/images/SOFBImposter.png))</sub>

> **Related Global Posts**
>
> **Donna Evans**
> I Keep Getting This Darn Message Popping Saying----Message
>   From Web Page  Stack Overflow @ Line
>   28 What The Hell Is This Anyone Know
>   Help Me Thanks a few seconds ago
>
> **Diane Bookwalter**
>  HELP I keep getting a pop up that say "Stack
>   overflow at line28" and then I can't
>   do anything. I can't click off and I
>   have to just restart the computer from
>   here ?? Any idea what's going on ??
>   Thanks 6 minutes ago · View Feedback
>   (6)
>
> **Mitzi Cotton**
>  OMG THIS FRIKKIN OUT OF MEMORY AND STACK OVERFLOW
>   ERRORS ARE MAKING ME
>   CRA....................................ZY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   9 minutes ago · Comment · Like · View
>   Feedback (4)
>
> **Karen Conner**
>  JUST WONDERING WHEN MY "OUT OF MEMORY" AND "STACK
>   OVERFLOW" ERRORS WILL BEGIN TO POP UP
>   AGAIN :-( 10 minutes ago · View
>   Feedback (3)
>
> **Ann Wilson Belford**
>  what is stack overflow? and what dose it mean
>   16 minutes ago

---

**EDIT**: It's all OK now, I altered the duplicate page so it looks correct now:

[image: All Better Now]
<sub>(source: [gitlin.name](http://josh.gitlin.name/images/SOFB-Fixed.jpg))</sub>

Comment: This is **so not Friday**.

Comment: LOL. Yes, I know. I am seriously asking what the duplicate page is. I just added FHC and unicorns to... um... well, I swear there was a reason but it escapes me now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In seriousness, one of the Stack Overflow administrators needs to contact Facebook and tell them that they are the real stack overflow and that page is an imposter.

Comment: Facebook has started automatically creating community pages, so not an imposter

Comment: What are these "community pages" you speak of? I think the smaller page needs to go, because it distracts people from finding the real page.

Comment: @Josh it's some new crap that facebook decided to use so that it could feel cool. For instance if you said before you go to McFarlane High School, you can't just say that now. You can only link to a community page. The major flaw in it is stuff like StackOverflow=Stack-Overflow and McFarlane, Oklahoma!=McFarlane, New York

Comment: Ugggg!!! What a mess. So this is probably not going away then huh? :-(

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what all the real vs fake stuff is about.

I started the ['page' on FB](https://www.facebook.com/pages/stackoverflow/11239244970) and the ['group' on LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=753957) just after the original beta. Chris started the ['group' on FB](https://www.facebook.com/groups/28714318518/) around the same time (confusingly FB has both groups and pages). I asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15815) (back before meta even existed) and Chris and I traded admin rights. Ultimately that question became community and then moved to meta.

I'm still an admin for the FB page and the LinkedIn group. Neither is strictly official, although there's now a [marketing person from StackExchange](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=8935583) on the admin lists for both pages.

The 'fake' page is just the one Facebook auto-generates for wikipedia entries, it's been reported as a duplicate, but FB typically isn't quick with these things. The related global posts is just pattern matching, I'd expect them to be fairly nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

Much better. The freehand circles are a significant improvement and help mitigate the terrible mess on that page.

That sparkly unicorn looks a little sick, though.

Comment: Sick, you say?  But [don't you like rainbows](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=1839#comic)?  (Finally, putting that link in my Meta profile pays off!)

Comment: It's not a sick as a zombie unicorn!

Comment: Sadly Cornify doesn't add Zombie Unicorns... anyone want to make Undead Cornify?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like neither is "official" - for example the FB group page was created by someone named "Chris" probably https://stackoverflow.com/users/13/chris-jester-young so there can't be really be a fake to something that is not official to start with. :-)

Edit: according to Pekka in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59358/stack-overflow-fan-page-on-facebook) this "fake" it auto generated by Facebook! :-D