# Display question view counts above 1k as n.n kviews until the count reaches 10k

Tags: feature-request, markdown, views

This is a rather trivial request, but I would imagine trivial to implement as well.  I just received a notable question badge on SU and when I look at my question list, it says 3 kviews, even though it only has 2500 views.  It looks like you want to limit the view count to 3 characters and 2.5 would fit.  So how about formatting kviews as n.n until they reach 10?

Comment: +1, but... how exact does the views count need to be, really?

Comment: @Pop: I know, I'm nitpicking, but there's room and it's a simple formatting issue, so I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: @Popular: See my answer. When you want 2.5K, 2K is deceptive when in reality it's 1.7K

Comment: @The, I did see your answer, but it's such an odd case. In general, there's no serious use for the views stat. For you, watching the question won't affect the number of views it gets, so there's little point in doing so. The number of views changes pretty slowly except in the rarest of cases. If you _really_ want to track the exact number, you can always open the question in a separate tab to see its stats. And the proposed change still won't help for those last 50 views.

Answer (score 12):

I like it. I keep watching the following, expecting that I am close to Notable Question for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50413/is-this-a-fake-stack-overflow-facebook-page-if-not-what-is-it):

[image: I'm so close!]

In reality [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50413/is-this-a-fake-stack-overflow-facebook-page-if-not-what-is-it) has 1,737 views. (No, I'm not doing all this just for more views! Ok, well [maybe I am](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50413/is-this-a-fake-stack-overflow-facebook-page-if-not-what-is-it). No, I am not! I swear... really... [:-)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50413/is-this-a-fake-stack-overflow-facebook-page-if-not-what-is-it)

I checked and sure enough, a single decimal would fit nicely!

[image: But yet, so far...]

So I think this would be a great feature.

Comment: "A watched question, never becomes Notable"

Comment: ROFLMAO @Jon, that was one of the better edits I've seen :-)

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that was the edit. +1 in spirit, @Jon.

Answer (score 5):

You can mouse over the number and the exact value will appear in the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, these are the current inaccuracies

```
        range : margin of error
    0 -  1000 :    0 %
 1001 -  1499 :   33 % (at 1499, it is off by 499 against 1499)
         1500 :   25 % (reported as 2K, the error is 500/2K)

         .... : (consistently decreasing)

      -  9499 :  5.3% (at 9499, it shows as 9.9kV, so the error is 499/9499)
 9500 - 10000 :  5.0% (at 9500, error is 500/10K)
        10499 :  4.99%
        10500 :  5   %

         .... : (consistently decreasing thereafter)
```

**(max of 33% off)**. Using x.x (1dp) for between 1k and 10k will **reduce the maximum inaccuracy to 4.8%** within the 1K-10K range, which is exactly the same as the inaccuracy for 10499 -> 10K.

```
        range : margin of error
    0 -  1000 :    0 %
 1001 -  1049 :  4.67%  (49/1049)
 1050 -  1149 :    0 % - 4.76%

         .... : (consistently decreasing)

      -  9949 :  0.49% (at 9949, it shows as 9.9kV, so the error is 49/9900)
 9950 - 10000 :  0.5 % (at 9500, error is 500/9500)
        10499 :  4.75%
        10500 :  4.76%

         .... : (consistently decreasing thereafter)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion I see that counter as a "milestone" meaning if I get a rounding to 2K it means my question has been viewed at least 2'000 times and then the question is in the 2'000 - 2'999 range.

Even mathematically the error could be bigger, in a user point of view, it seems that logic make sense, no?

Comment: It rounds up starting at 2.5k, so it actually means that the question is in the 2000 to 2499 range.

Comment: Not true for me the actual question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5619395/628006) have 1'595 views and it still shows 2K...  Does it means the ".5" rounding starts only after 2K, meaning "1.5K" does not exists?