# Profile page says question viewed 2K times but it was actually 1501

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-page

[My profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176769/karlphillip) displays **2K views** for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052940/win32-how-to-make-an-opengl-rendering-context-with-transparent-background), but when I opened the question itself to check out how many views it has gotten I discovered it had only **1501 views**.

What's up with that?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79831/display-question-view-counts-above-1k-as-n-n-kviews-until-the-count-reaches-10k

Comment: **EXACT** duplicate of [Wrong view count for questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14118/wrong-view-count-for-questions)

Comment: @Adam, for extremely large values of 1501 -- or extremely small values of 1508 -- perhaps.

Comment: @Popular My `EXACT()` function only has two significant digits, but it runs *really* fast on 8 bit processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the design goal to KISS - the simplest way to keep things at 3 digits is to break it into 2 buckets. The pre-K and the post-K (1K).  So you get these inaccuracies

```
        range : margin of error
    0 -  1000 :    0 %
 1001 -  1499 :   33 % (at 1499, it is off by 499 against 1499)
         1500 :   25 % (reported as 2K, the error is 500/2K)

         .... : (consistently decreasing)

      -  9499 :  5.3% (at 9499, it shows as 9.9kV, so the error is 499/9499)
 9500 - 10000 :  5.0% (at 9500, error is 500/10K)
        10499 :  4.99%
        10500 :  5   %

         .... : (consistently decreasing thereafter)
```

This is what implementing the [related request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79831/156011) will achieve:

```
        range : margin of error
    0 -  1000 :    0 %
 1001 -  1049 :  4.67%  (49/1049)
 1050 -  1149 :    0 % - 4.76%

         .... : (consistently decreasing)

      -  9949 :  0.49% (at 9949, it shows as 9.9kV, so the error is 49/9900)
 9950 - 10000 :  0.5 % (at 9500, error is 500/9500)
        10499 :  4.75%
        10500 :  4.76%

         .... : (consistently decreasing thereafter)
```

Answer (score 3):

1501 rounded to kilos is 2k ;-)

Still, when placing your cursor over the 2k, you should have a tooltip displaying the real number.

Here's an example from my own SO account :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/meta-83047.png))</sub>

Comment: That's a big, big rounding. It's like saying the tank of your car is full when you have only 51% gas in it.

Comment: @Karl - you mean 75%, in which case you are right

Comment: @Richard it's not rounding between 0 and 2000, it's rounding between 1000 ("empty") and 2000 ("full")

Comment: @Daniel You're wrong. See my full bodied answer below. Saying that 1501 (1500 for that matter) is 2k is a 25% error. Saying a half tank of car is full is a 50% error. Big difference