# View count are shown highly inflated in display

Tags: bug, views, information-display, rounding

[image]

View count for my post [How can never ending decimal numbers represent finite lengths? e.g. $\pi$, $\sqrt{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696830/how-can-never-ending-decimal-numbers-represent-finite-lengths-e-g-pi-sqr) has barely touched 2500 and it shows 3k view in the display, which is 20% inflated from the original!
Should be a reasonable ceiling value.

Comment: Looks like it got rounded up to the nearest thousand, which seems somewhat reasonable... Given that you can see the exact value just by hovering over the approximated value, I'm not sure this is a significant enough issue to justify changing this.

Comment: @V2Blast Mobile users cannot see the full view count.

Comment: @V2Blast, (1) when the view count is in "thousand"-s, shouldn't it round off to the nearest hundred? It's understandable that it rounds off to the nearest thousand when the view count is in "10s of thousand". (2) Many people may not hover their mouse on a view count info; They take it at a face value. (3) Suppose view count is 9501 and if it rounds off to 10k ; But then no gold badge yet for that user!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong view count for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14118/wrong-view-count-for-questions) // See also: [Profile page says question viewed 2K times but it was actually 1501](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83047/513150)

Comment: "*Many people may not hover their mouse on a view count info; They take it at a face value.*" so what, exactly? Somebody thought there were 500 irrelevant units more than there were. You don't really need a view count to be totally accurate. There is no meaningful difference between 2.5k and 3k. The number is a bit arbitrary anyway - could be 2.5k people, could be 500 people who generated them. And you can never know. "*Suppose view count is 9501 and if it rounds off to 10k ; But then no gold badge yet for that user!*" truly a tragedy for the ages. How would the user recover from the shock?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Profile page says question viewed 2K times but it was actually 1501](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83058/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14118/282094 or https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/282094

Comment: @Rob yes but why close as duplicate of a duplicate, when it's 100% the same as the original? Dupe chains are nice to wear, but serve no real purpose when there's no difference between the links.

Comment: @Sha, because it's a better answer.

Comment: @Rob not really. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14119/152859) is correct and simple. No need to make it complicated with formula, percentages, etc. Generally I agree, if there's dupe with a better answer it might be better to choose it, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @sha, then don't ask.