# 10k Views Badge

Tags: support, views, view-badges

I was browsing my reputation/questions, and I noticed that one of my questions has 10k views. However, it doesn't show the 10k view "Famous Question" badge on my account.

Is "10k views" a rounded figure that will show 10k between 9500-10499? Also, does that mean that the "Famous Question" badge is only earned after receiving 10000+ views?

Comment: it's up to 9,805 and counting...

Comment: Related: [Wrong view count for questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14118), [Profile page says question viewed 2K times but it was actually 1501](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83047), and this feature request: [Display question view counts above 1k as n.n kviews until the count reaches 10k](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79831)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can see the actual number of views on the [question's page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235687/open-graph-namespace-declaration-html-with-xmlns-or-head-prefix):

[image]

Or just hover over the larger (rounded) view count:

[image]

You currently have ~9,785 views, not 10,000.

Comment: +1 for that beautiful freehand circle

Comment: LOL Thank you for the screenshots and multiple ways to locate the actual view count.

Answer (score 15):

Looking at your profile, I see the "10k views" on one of your questions, but mousing over the view count reveals 9,783 views.  So, it rounds up, and you won't get the badge quite yet.

Comment: Does this mean we have to change our standard, "Caching; it's always caching" reply to this sort of thing to add, "Unless it's rounding; always rounding"?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Caching or rounding; it's always caching or rounding.

Comment: Or oscillating.

Comment: Sometimes all three

Comment: @LBT Okay, I got it. So, it's "Caching, rounding, or oscillating; it's always caching, rounding, or oscillating". I have to admit, that *does* roll right off the tongue.

Comment: Unless it isn't.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Our three weapons are caching, rounding, oscillating, and an almost fanatical devotion to Trogdor!

Comment: @Gilles *almost?*

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yes, that's the [quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spanish_Inquisition_(Monty_Python)).

Comment: Oh, you guys. LOL. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewBarber and when it's neither caching, rounding, nor oscillating, the answer is probably in a tooltip somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a rounded figure. If you go to the question itself, it shows that it has 9000 or so views, which is probably too much to fit in the list of your questions.