# Stack Overflow fan page on facebook

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, facebook, social-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow on social networks (LinkedIn, facebook, hi5!, Orkut)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15815/stack-overflow-on-social-networks-linkedin-facebook-hi5-orkut)

Why is there no Stack Overflow fan page on facebook?

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6885/stackoverflows-presence-on-facebook-could-be-a-bit-better/18644#18644

Answer (score 1):

There [is one](http://www.facebook.com/#!/pages/Stack-Overflow/105665906133609?ref=ts). I think it's auto generated by Facebook - what's being posted there doesn't look very official.

Comment: Yeah, Facebook basically autogenerated fan pages for the English Wikipedia at one point. Which of course lead to great fan page ads such as "Become a fan of Sebaceous cyst!" and it only went down from there.